merge multiple files using full join by the first column
I have a directory with 200 samples. Each file has two columns. I want to full join these files and make a joined file
This is the example of
$ head 346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525 95.2
1_10526 98.9690721649485
1_10542 80.8
1_10543 87.6288659793814

$ head 346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525 95.7142857142857
1_10526 98.1132075471698
1_10542 78.5714285714286
1_10549 75.4716981132076

I want to join all files based on the first column and if any file does not have the correcponding first column put NA in the merge file.
here is the example output
$ head merged.csv
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076

So I want comma delimited format output, the first column is the column used for joining and the rest columns are the corresponding file names. As you see NA is placed when prob is not present in any file.
I wrote this
# Create an empty result file
output_file="full_joined_result.txt"
> "$output_file"

# Loop over all files in the directory
for file in *_format; do
  # If output file is empty, initialize with the first file's data
  if [ ! -s "$output_file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$output_file"
  else
    # Full join with the next file based on the first column
    awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next} {print a[$1], $0}' "$output_file" "$file" > temp && mv temp "$output_file"
  fi
done

But does not give the output I want.
I appreciate if anyone could help fixing this.

If one of the input files is empty should it appear in the output with NA in every data field or should it not appear in the output at all?

Are all of the first column values unique within each input file?

Using any awk no matter how many input files you have and whether or not any of them are empty:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
{
    probs[$1]
    vals[$1 FS FILENAME] = $2
}
END {
    out = "Prob"
    for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
        out = out OFS ARGV[i]
    }
    print out

    for ( prob in probs ) {
        out = prob
        for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
            key = prob FS ARGV[i]
            out = out OFS ( key in vals ? vals[key] : "NA" )
        }
        print out
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk *.cov_format
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286

If you need the data lines sorted for output there are several options including using GNU awk and adding a PROCINFO["sorted_in"] line:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
{
    probs[$1]
    vals[$1 FS FILENAME] = $2
}
END {
    out = "Prob"
    for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
        out = out OFS ARGV[i]
    }
    print out

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( prob in probs ) {
        out = prob
        for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
            key = prob FS ARGV[i]
            out = out OFS ( key in vals ? vals[key] : "NA" )
        }
        print out
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk *.cov_format
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076

or with any awk just piping the second print out to sort, e.g.:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
{
    probs[$1]
    vals[$1 FS FILENAME] = $2
}
END {
    out = "Prob"
    for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
        out = out OFS ARGV[i]
    }
    print out

    for ( prob in probs ) {
        out = prob
        for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++ ) {
            key = prob FS ARGV[i]
            out = out OFS ( key in vals ? vals[key] : "NA" )
        }
        print out | "sort"
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk *.cov_format
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076


Using a gawk script called script.awk:
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
BEGINFILE { covs[FILENAME] }

{
    probs[$1][FILENAME] = $2
}

END {
    out = "Prob"
    for ( cov in covs ) out = out OFS cov
    print out

    for ( prob in probs ) {
        out = prob
        for ( cov in covs ) out = out OFS ( cov in probs[prob] ? probs[prob][cov] : "NA" )
        print out
    }
}

awk -f script.awk *.cov_format

Be careful, this is using multiple arrays that will be loaded in memory, so if you have to much data it may not work.
That script uses arrays of arrays, that is a GNU awk specification.
How it work :

BEGIN{} at the beginning of the script
OFS define output field separator
BEGINFILE{} at the beginning of each file
array[] using an array
FILENAME the name of the current file
multi_dimensional_array[][] using a multi dimensional array, this is gawk specific
END{} at the end of the script
for() a for loop
for (key in array) scan all element in an array
if ? then : else ternary operator

If you want to sort the output you may add PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" before the first for loop.

Since you're using GNU awk you could use probs[$1][ARGIND] instead of probs[$1][FILENAME] and then for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++) { cov=ARGV[i]; ... } instead of for ( cov in covs ) and that'd have 2 main benefits: 1) no need for BEGINFILE { covs[FILENAME] }, and 2) the output columns will be in the same order as the input file names (today can be shuffled by in). It'd probably also use slightly less memory for the array indices. probs[prob][cov] and similar would obviously become probs[prob][i].

I couldn't come up with a more elegant solution, however this should get the job done.
The idea is to:

Concatenate all files ending in _format, extracting the first field and filtering out duplicates, sorting the output; this is done in order to create a "base" file containing all the (unique and sorted) keys.
Build on top of the base file, reading every file ending in _format one by one and "left joining" it on field #1 of the base file; this is done by using join + Bash's brace expansion (I previously used Awk to make up for the potentially missing fields after each join; being able to generate the field numbers in advance, which is a trick I shamelessy stole from Thor's answer made it possible to leverage join's -e option without having to resort to Awk).
The header is also progressively built on top of the base header Prob, by appending , followed by the current filename at each iteration; after every file has been processed, the header and the output CSV are concatenated and printed to STDOUT.

#!/usr/bin/env bash

cut -d' ' -f1 *_format |
    sort -u >out

header=Prob
nf=1

for f in *_format; do
    fi=$(eval "printf '%s ' 1.{1..$nf} 2.2")

    join -t, -j1 -a1 -o${fi} -eNA out <(sort "${f}" | tr ' ' ,) >temp

    mv temp out
    header+=,${f}

    (( nf++ ))
done

<<<"${header}" cat - out

rm out

% ./script.sh 
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076


With bash and join (assuming your files are sorted).
The idea here is to:

Find all valid keys.
For each data-file generate a join command.
Pipe it all together.
Execute the pipe in a sub-shell.

# A counter keeping tabs on how many columns we have
i=1

# Find all valid keys
cmd="cut -d' ' -f1 *format | sort -u |\n"

# Generate a join command for each file
for f in *format; do
  fields=$(eval "echo 1.{1..$i} 2.2")
  cmd+="join -o'$fields' -a1 -eNA - $f |\n"
  ((i++))
done

# Close the pipe
cmd+="cat"

# Execute $cmd
printf "$cmd" | bash

Output:
1_10525 95.2 95.7142857142857
1_10526 98.9690721649485 98.1132075471698
1_10542 80.8 78.5714285714286
1_10543 87.6288659793814 NA
1_10549 NA 75.4716981132076

The generated command looks like this:
cut -d' ' -f1 *format | sort -u |
join -o'1.1 2.2' -a1 -eNA - 346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format |
join -o'1.1 1.2 2.2' -a1 -eNA - 346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format |
cat

To include a header with the output you could use a compound statement, e.g.:
{
  printf "Prob %s\n" "$(printf "%s\n" *format | paste -sd' ')"
  printf "$cmd" | bash
} | column -t

Output:
Prob     346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format  346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525  95.2                                 95.7142857142857
1_10526  98.9690721649485                     98.1132075471698
1_10542  80.8                                 78.5714285714286
1_10543  87.6288659793814                     NA
1_10549  NA                                   75.4716981132076

Convert to CSV by piping into tr -s ' ' ,, e.g.:
{
  printf "Prob %s\n" "$(printf "%s\n" *format | paste -sd' ')"
  printf "$cmd" | bash
} | tr -s ' ' ,

Output:
Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076


Nice trick with the brace expansion to generate the field numbers, I didn't think of that. I might steal it to get rid of the ugly Awk command :P

As a matter of fact, I did, I hope you don't mind.

@kos: I don't mind at all. This trick is needed with bash because it parses variables later than brace expansion, however other shells don't have this issue, e.g. zsh

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -e '#declare variables
            my ($allkeys, $subkeys) = SetHash.new; my %hash;

            #collect all keys
            $allkeys{ $_.[0] }++ for lines.map(*.words);

            #set-up special cat-handle
            my $cat = IO::CatHandle.new: :on-switch{
                if $++ { 
                    for ($allkeys (-) $subkeys).keys -> $missing { %hash.push: $missing => "NA" 
                };  $subkeys = Nil; }}, @*ARGS;

            #loop through lines to create final hash, keeping track of keys-per-file
            for $cat.lines.map(*.words) -> $a { $subkeys{ $a.[0] }++;  %hash.push( $a.[0] => $a.[1] ) };

            #output
            %hash.push: "#Prob" => $_ for @*ARGS; .say for %hash.sort;'   *.cov_format

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku is a full-featured, Unicode-aware language that has many advantageous structures/objects. Here we make use of Raku's built-in SetHash data structure, which is like Raku's built-in Sets, but mutable. The general outline of the code is as follows:

Loop through all lines of all files, collect the first column elements into a new SetHash object called $allkeys.

Create a CatHandle which is an IO object that here takes files off the command line in the @*ARGS dynamic array. An important feature of CatHandles in Raku is that you can specify an on-switch directive, which executes code when the handle switches to the next file.

Loop through all lines of all files, this time using the special $cat CatHandle. Lines  (lines) are broken into (whitespace-separated) words, which are then pushed onto the %hash.

The $cat CatHandle runs code in the on-switch directive that compares the $allkeys keys with the per-file $subkeys (the (-) code-symbol stands for set-difference). Any $missing keys are assigned the NA value, ensuring that each key has a value for each file. After running, the $subkeys SetHash is emptied, reading the object for the next file.

All files are read-in to %hash using the $cat CatHandle, and $missing keys accounted for (i.e. inserting a placeholder "NA" value), during the :on-switch phase. A header line is added to %hash using #Prob as key so it sorts to the top, then resultant %hash is sorted and output.


Sample Input:
$ cat 346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525 95.2
1_10526 98.9690721649485
1_10542 80.8
1_10543 87.6288659793814

$ cat 346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525 95.7142857142857
1_10526 98.1132075471698
1_10542 78.5714285714286
1_10549 75.4716981132076

Sample Output (using say and without joining):
#Prob => [346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format 346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format]
1_10525 => [95.2 95.7142857142857]
1_10526 => [98.9690721649485 98.1132075471698]
1_10542 => [80.8 78.5714285714286]
1_10543 => [87.6288659793814 NA]
1_10549 => [NA 75.4716981132076]

Sample Output (using put and joining on commas):
#Prob,346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format,346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format
1_10525,95.2,95.7142857142857
1_10526,98.9690721649485,98.1132075471698
1_10542,80.8,78.5714285714286
1_10543,87.6288659793814,NA
1_10549,NA,75.4716981132076

For the comma-separated output at bottom, replace the final .say code-output statement with:
for %hash.sort { for $_.kv -> $k,$v { put $k ~ "," ~ $v.join: "," }};'

https://docs.raku.org/routine/SetHash
https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/CatHandle
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-Set_difference_operator-Set_difference_operator
https://raku.org

AND you can even use duckdb to import the tables via Duckie :-)

Using join from coreutils, and sponge from moreutils:
#!/bin/sh

# Get the list of files to join.
# (These are assumed to be sorted on the first field.)
set -- *.cov_format

# Start accumulating data on top of the first file.
cp "$1" merged
shift

# For each of the other files, join it with the
# "merged" file, and write the result back to the
# "merged" file.
for file do
        join -a 1 -a 2 -e NA -o auto merged "$file" | sponge merged
done

# Create the header and convert the spaces in "merged"
# to commas.
{
        {
                # The header is the word "Prob" and
                # the names of all the files.
                echo Prob
                printf '%s\n' *.cov_format
        } | paste -d , -s
        tr ' ' , <merged
} >merged.csv

rm merged

The command
join -a 1 -a 2 -e NA -o auto merged "$file"

... will merge the files merged and $file on the default join field (the first field) and keep all lines, including those not joined.  Any empty fields resulting from the inability to join a line are replaced by the string NA.
This solution trades high memory consumption with disk I/O.  It will, at most, store a single line from either file in memory but will rewrite the accumulated file merged in each iteration of the loop.

Just use DuckDB
select
    coalesce(A.key, B.key) k,
    A.val val_A,
    B.val val_B
from
    read_csv('346_T1_A_deduped.bismark.cov_format', names =['key', 'val'], delim = ' ') as A
full outer join read_csv('346_T1_B_deduped.bismark.cov_format', names =['key', 'val'], delim = ' ') as B on
    B.key = A.key;

And then you can save your results in whatever database or format you want ;-)
